# clojure.core unquote and unquote-splicing

Tags: clojure

At the top of the clojure.core file (below the comments and the namespace declaration) there are two definitions with no extra code or information:

```
(def unquote)
(def unquote-splicing)
```

What do these do/why are they there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are kind of dummy values. The reader expands `~x` to `(unquote x)` and `~@x` to `(unquote-splice x)`. Lists of these types are then handled specially in syntax-quote.

Their declaration allows also their use outside of syntax-quote, e.g. in your own macros.

Since they are not bound to anything, their use outside of syntax-quote or a macro which handles them throws an exception.